# Como usar uma função de um objeto como argumento de outra função

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientação-a-objetos

Essa é minha função que recebe um objeto e utiliza os atributos do tipo "**function**".

```
FrameWork.prototype.loop = function (objectLoop) {

    objectLoop.draw();
    objectLoop.update();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
};
```

Esse é o objeto que eu passo para a function loop (***game*** é minha instância de ***FrameWork*** e *FrameWork* está em um arquivo .js separado)

```
game.loop({
        draw : function(){

            game.get.Context.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);

            game.get.Context.fillStyle = colider.color;
            game.get.Context.fillRect(colider.x, colider.y, colider.width, colider.height);

            game.get.Context.fillStyle = player.color;
            game.get.Context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
        },
        update: function () {
            updateBlock();
            colide();
            wallCollision();
        }
    });
```

Erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: objectLoop.draw is not a function.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando passas a callback a `window.requestAnimationFrame` a função `loop` vai ser corrida de novo. Irá correr com o contexto certo porque usas `.bind(this)` mas sem argumentos. O `objectLoop` não estará definido se não o passares no `.bind` também;

Para passar também esse objeto usa assim:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this, objectLoop));
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado (chega ser engraçado ser só um detalhe desse).